# ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR when connecting to local WordPress MySQL database from NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, wordpress

I can't seem to access the local WordPress MySql database. Inside a server.js file I have the following:

```
 var con = mysql.createConnection({
 connectionLimit :   100,
  host : 'localhost',
  port: '3306',
  user : 'bn_wordpress',
  password : '1857dd46f4',
  database : 'bitnami_wordpress'
});
con.connect();
```

and this is the package.json file:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "4.13.3",
        "body-parser": "1.14.1",
        "socket.io": "1.3.7",
        "mysql": "2.18.1",
        "dateformat": "1.0.12"
    }
}
```

I got the name of the database and port from wp-config.php from this line:

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define( 'DB_NAME', 'bitnami_wordpress' );

/** MySQL database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'bn_wordpress' );

/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '1857dd46f4' );

/** MySQL hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost:3306' );
```

When I connect by typing `mysql -u root -p bitnami_wordpress` in the terminal, I am able to successfully access the database.

But when i run `npm start`, the following error gets thrown:

```
> @ start /Users/ciaodejan/Downloads/Integrating WordPress Chatroom using nodejs and socket.io/Nodejs
> node server.js

Listening on 81
/Users/ciaodejan/Downloads/Integrating WordPress Chatroom using nodejs and socket.io/Nodejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (/Users/ciaodejan/Downloads/Integrating WordPress Chatroom using nodejs and socket.io/Nodejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (/Users/ciaodejan/Downloads/Integrating WordPress Chatroom using nodejs and socket.io/Nodejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:123:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/Users/ciaodejan/Downloads/Integrating WordPress Chatroom using nodejs and socket.io/Nodejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/Users/ciaodejan/Downloads/Integrating WordPress Chatroom using nodejs and socket.io/Nodejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (/Users/ciaodejan/Downloads/Integrating WordPress Chatroom using nodejs and socket.io/Nodejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (/Users/ciaodejan/Downloads/Integrating WordPress Chatroom using nodejs and socket.io/Nodejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/ciaodejan/Downloads/Integrating WordPress Chatroom using nodejs and socket.io/Nodejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/ciaodejan/Downloads/Integrating WordPress Chatroom using nodejs and socket.io/Nodejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/ciaodejan/Downloads/Integrating WordPress Chatroom using nodejs and socket.io/Nodejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/Users/ciaodejan/Downloads/Integrating WordPress Chatroom using nodejs and socket.io/Nodejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/Users/ciaodejan/Downloads/Integrating WordPress Chatroom using nodejs and socket.io/Nodejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ciaodejan/Downloads/Integrating WordPress Chatroom using nodejs and socket.io/Nodejs/server.js:28:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
    at Connection._handleProtocolError (/Users/ciaodejan/Downloads/Integrating WordPress Chatroom using nodejs and socket.io/Nodejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:423:8)
    at Protocol.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Protocol._delegateError (/Users/ciaodejan/Downloads/Integrating WordPress Chatroom using nodejs and socket.io/Nodejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:398:10)
    at Handshake.<anonymous> (/Users/ciaodejan/Downloads/Integrating WordPress Chatroom using nodejs and socket.io/Nodejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:153:12)
    at Handshake.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Handshake.Sequence.end (/Users/ciaodejan/Downloads/Integrating WordPress Chatroom using nodejs and socket.io/Nodejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:78:12)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (/Users/ciaodejan/Downloads/Integrating WordPress Chatroom using nodejs and socket.io/Nodejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:125:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/Users/ciaodejan/Downloads/Integrating WordPress Chatroom using nodejs and socket.io/Nodejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/Users/ciaodejan/Downloads/Integrating WordPress Chatroom using nodejs and socket.io/Nodejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (/Users/ciaodejan/Downloads/Integrating WordPress Chatroom using nodejs and socket.io/Nodejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10) {
  code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
  errno: 1045,
  sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)",
  sqlState: '28000',
  fatal: true
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

This is the full server.js file:

```
var app = require("express")();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http);
var mysql = require("mysql");
var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
   

app.use(require("express").static('data'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

//conncecting nodejs to remote mysql
var con = mysql.createConnection({
 connectionLimit :   100,
  host : 'localhost',
  port: '3306',
  user : 'bn_wordpress',
  password : '1857dd46f4',
  database : 'bitnami_wordpress'
});
con.connect();


//  getting today's date  
var now = new Date();
var today=dateFormat(now, "mmmm dS, yyyy");

// This is auto initiated event when Client connects to Your Machine.  
io.on('connection',function(socket){  

  // authenticating  and getting user name from wp_usermeta table. 
  socket.on('validate',function(data){
    var query="select meta_value from wp_usermeta where meta_key = 'nickname' and user_id = '" + data + "'";
    con.query(String(query),function(err,rows){
      if(rows.length>0){
        
        //Getting all the messages 
        var get_message="select * from chats";
        con.query(String(get_message),function(err,get_message_rows){
            
            // saving username in socket object 
            socket.nickname=rows[0].meta_value;

            //sending response to client side code.  
            io.emit('user entrance',{
              info:rows[0].meta_value+" is online.",
              message:get_message_rows
            }); 
        });

      }
    });
  });
    
  //inserting messages to tables and sending the messages to client side code. 
  socket.on('send msg',function(data){
    var query="insert into chats values ('','"+data.msg+"','"+data.id+"','"+socket.nickname+"','"+today+"')";
    con.query(String(query),function(err,rows){});
    io.emit('get msg',{user:socket.nickname,message:data.msg,id:data.id,date:today});
  });

  //When user dissconnects from server.
  socket.on('disconnect',function(){
    io.emit('exit',{message:socket.nickname});
  });

});


http.listen(81,function(){
    console.log("Listening on 81");
});
```

**UPDATE**: I have noticed I'm having trouble starting the mysql service and `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status` shows

```
php-fpm not running
apache not running
mysql not running
```

**UPDATE 2**: I have restarted the whole application and now everything is running properly but the access denied error persists.

```
root@debian:~# sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status
php-fpm already running
apache already running
mysql already running
```

Comment: Make sure you change your password after this ;)

Comment: This is just a local Bitnami WordPress installation, so I'm not worried about the password being shown.

Comment: Can you update the error please. It's now wrong with all the edits and not helpful